# Why the audio is not being played while using MediaPlayer Instance?

Tags: android, media-player

When I click the `play` button the song with resource Id `R.raw.dance` is not being played . When I am using the same way to play audio's in other app,the audios are being played . Here the audio is a bit too long than those in other app . Does that have any effect? What possible mistake I am doing here which results in no audio? How can I rectify it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
private MediaPlayer media;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        media=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.dance);
        Button play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                media.start();

            }

        });

        Button pause=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                media.pause();

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to perform a `reset()`?
And also, one possible debug would be to see if MediaPlayer's `isPlaying()` returns `true` or `false`; this allows to understand if it's a coding problem (MediaPlayer does not support it for some reason) or an audio problem (MediaPlayer plays it but it's not hearable)

Comment: @Beppi's I don't think I need to call `reset()` and I tried to test using `isPlaying()` method by showing a Toast if `isPlaying()` returns true but no Toast appeared.What could be the problem now?